# How do I add a dropdown in magento header

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, magento-enterprise, database, ce-1.9.0.1

How do I add  a dropdown in magento header with auto fill with city names and when clicked on those city names its redirected to given links. please let me know the possible solutions . My requirement is almost similar to http://in.bookmyshow.com/

Help me in doing this I am struggling

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more in your question about what it is you're trying to accomplish, where these cities come from and what you've tried so far

Comment: This requirement is quite broad - there's a lot involved. Try some things (perhaps find an extension which does some of this) and see what you see.

Answer (score 0):

hurrey i found solution got to  cms>static bloks>header toplinks
put this code at the bottom of that cms content block

[1:13:17 PM] shiva reddy: Enter City

Bangalore
Chennai
Hyderabad
Cochin
Mumbai
Kolkata